# C++ program freezes when trying to display a triangle with vertices read from data file

Tags: c++, opengl, file-io

I wrote a small program that reads 3 vertices of type double from a data file and displays them as a triangle (using lines). It compiles, but when I run it the window always freezes. I tried debugging it, but without success. I also created a separate program that reads the same data the same way but without displaying it graphically. It worked. I suppose the problem is in my openGL commands.

Could you point out my mistake(s)?

```
//to compile, use   $ g++ -lGL -lglut Triangulation.cpp -o Triangulation


    #include <iostream>
    #include <GL/glut.h>
    #include <fstream>//for operation on files
    using namespace std;

    double triangle_vertices[3][2];

    void Draw_Triangulation() {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glColor3f(0.8, 0.8, 0.0);//color of the shape (Red,Green,Blue). red+green=yellow

        int i=0;    
        ifstream myfile ("data.txt"); //read from file
        if (myfile.is_open()) {
            while (myfile.good()) {
                for (i;i<3;i++) {
                for (int j=0;j<2;j++) {
                    myfile >> triangle_vertices[i][j];
                }
                }
            }
        cout<<"file successfuly read."<<endl;
        }
        myfile.close();

        i=0;    
            glBegin(GL_LINES); //display line with vertices 2&0
            glVertex3f(triangle_vertices[i+2][0],triangle_vertices[i+2][1],0.0);
            glVertex3f(triangle_vertices[i][0],triangle_vertices[i][1],0.0);
            glEnd();    
        for (i;i<2;i++) {  //display lines with vertices 0&1 and 1&2
            glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex3f(triangle_vertices[i][0],triangle_vertices[i][1],0.0);
            glVertex3f(triangle_vertices[i+1][0],triangle_vertices[i+1][1],0.0);
            glEnd();
        }
    glFlush();
    }





    void Initialize() {
        glClearColor(0.32, 0.49, 0.46, 0.0);//(Red,Green,Blue,Alpha) initializes background color.
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    }

    int main(int iArgc, char** cppArgv) {
        glutInit(&iArgc, cppArgv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
        glutInitWindowSize(600, 600); //600*600 pixel window
        glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
        glutCreateWindow("Triangulation From Data File"); //Title of the window
        Initialize();
        glutDisplayFunc(Draw_Triangulation);

        glutMainLoop();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading a file from disk is an extremely slow operation, definitely now something you want to do in your Draw method (which ideally is called 30+ times per second). You should read the vertex data before hand (in main) and store it in a structure which you can then access from your `DrawTriangulation` method.

Comment: How would you do it differently? I still want to read the data from file. Should I read it outside of the function Draw_Triangulation()?

Comment: Read the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I somehow missed the last sentence. It worked! Thank you!